# What is the shell command to let a Linux box go sleep?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a shell script to check the I/O activity of a Linux box and if the server is quiet for a certain long time, the script should let the server go to sleep. But, after some Google searching, I didn't find a answer yet. Is there a shell script command to put a Linux box to sleep?

Comment: what shell are you using? Bash?

Answer (score 3):

Using the handy [pm-utils](http://pm-utils.freedesktop.org/wiki/) package, you can issue commands to suspend and hibernate without echo'ing values to the system. For example:

```
$ pm-suspend
$ pm-hibernate
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question simply, `echo -n mem > /sys/power/state` or `apm -z` should bring your linux system to sleep, depending on whether it uses ACPI or APM. However not all is necessarily happy, and you might want to take a look at [this article](http://www.linux.com/news/hardware/laptops/8253-how-to-suspend-and-hibernate-a-laptop-under-linux) about how to restore the video memory and sleep a system properly from a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

If your setup supports hibernation you can use the sys interface

```
echo -n mem >/sys/power/state
```

to suspend to ram and

```
echo -n disk >/sys/power/state
```

to suspend to disk.

Remind that your kernel and hardware have to support it to use it.